# A random '#.XXXXXXXXXXX' string is added to my URL when I use the AddThis code?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, addthis

I have added "AddThis" to my website and this is the code I have used :

```
        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" addthis:url="http://facebook.com/MySpills" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
            <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fabf4922f71c398"></script>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Now for some reason, every time I go to a page this happens to the URL:

```
http://domain/page#.T7FTDJ8ti28
```

The `#.T7FTDJ8ti28` changes every time I refresh the page, and I am concerned that this might confuse Google or other search engines. It also just doesn't look good to have it in the URL, so how can I get rid of it?

Comment: that's called a [HASH](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics#.T7FT9Z9YtDE), and it's needed so AddThis can track the links.

Comment: what exactly do they track with that??? and does it affect SEO?

Comment: @JohnFlatness thanks for that, please add that as an answer

Comment: On closer inspection, balexandre had already posted the same link.

Comment: My bad I didnt see that, @balexandre could you post the link as an answer so I can close this question??

Comment: To get rid of it, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328291/2871951) answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is commonly calling: [a HASH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and it serves to several things.

In **AddThis** context, it serves to track links in a way so they know what is a **direct link** and a **shared link**.

All is explained in their [**analytics article**](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics#.T7FzAOtBl8F).

This will not have any impact on Search Engine Optimization (SEO) as the rule is to track the regular link part and not the hashed part.

---

If, by the way, you want to know more on how the hash part of a web address is used for, the link below is a good start point article to read.

> [Are We Breaking the Web With a Hash and a Bang?](http://web.appstorm.net/general/opinion/are-we-breaking-the-web-with-a-hash-and-a-bang/)

Comment: More properly known as an anchor fragment or fragment identifier, for anyone Googling.

Comment: @Brad in javascript work is called a **hash** as you get that from `window.location.hash`

Comment: @balexandre I'm well aware... just calling out another name so someone can Google for what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};
```

To

```
var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};
```

Comment: +1 , This is the correct answer for in-site URL. But it also adds this hash when you share something in Social Media. How do we turn that off?