# How to configure addthis so that it won't create the hash data in the URL that I am going to share?

Tags: jquery, addthis

When I share a page, addthis creates some data/ infomation after my share URL with a hash(#) - how I can configure addthis so that it won't create the hash data in the URL that I am going to share?

For instance, addthis makes these,

```
http://mywebsite.com/#.Ufs8RtZRjpU.facebook
http://mywebsite.com/#.Ufs8oc2zPtQ.twitter
```

I am after,

```
http://mywebsite.com/
http://mywebsite.com/
```

Is it possible?

**edit:**

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = { pubid: "lauthiamkok", data_track_addressbar:false };</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=lauthiamkok"></script> 
<!-- AddThis Button END -->

<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
</script>
```

Tried this but does not work. Addthis is still a pain after years using it!

Answer (score 7):

I think what you're wanting to disable is clickback tracking, and in your question you're trying to disable address bar tracking. Try this instead:

```
var addthis_config = {
       data_track_clickback: false 
}
```

Found this [here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381252-click-tracking).

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and you are correct: data_track_clickback is what's required on this case. AddThis documentation is not clear about this and the two options have similar names: data_track_clickback and data_track_addressbar.

Comment: Excellent. AddThis' documentation isn't fantastic, so thanks for providing this. Also, this is the real answer, OP.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/352733-how-to-remove-hash-from-url-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
</script>
```

Okay try moving the add_config line above the widget

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
</script>

<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = { pubid: "lauthiamkok", data_track_addressbar:false };</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=lauthiamkok"></script> 
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Comment: yup it is. Did you try this code. You have to load the widget <script src=..." AFTER you write this line. Have you done that? i.e this needs to be something like `var addthis_config = {
     pubid: "YOUR-PROFILE-ID",
     data_track_addressbar:false
}`

Comment: yes I did. nothing has changed. I even have turned off the tracking in my addthis account and it goes no where! take a look in my edit. thanks.

Comment: no i mean the other way around. i.e Move Addthis widget call after the line of code. See my edit in the answer

Comment: damn! can i have a link to your page? it might be easier to diagnose

Comment: k last thing try removing var before addthis_config `addthis_config = { pubid: "YOUR-PROFILE-ID", data_track_addressbar:false }`

Comment: also remove the first addthis_config

Comment: I just did but... i'm giving up! take a look at the same link above please.

Comment: http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#data_track_addressbar=false see if it works. Otherwise, i am out of ideas

Comment: no worries. addthis team should look into this! thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a JavaScript function and used it on load....

```
 function onloader() {
            var v = window.location.href;
            v = v.replace(/\#.*/, '');
            window.location.href.replace = v;
        }
        $(window).load(function () {
            onloader();
        });
```

that did work for me... :) hope that will work for every one :D